# Change the css class associated with a <TD> column based on value of column with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a grid and for one of the columns i want to dynamically change the css used based on the value of another field in the resultset.

So instead of something like

```
<td class='class1'>
    ${firstname}
</td>
```

pseudo-wise I would like

```
{{if anotherColumnIsTrue }}
 <td class='class1'>
  ${firstname}
 </td>
{{/if}}
{{if !anotherColumnIsTrue }}
 <td class='class2'>
  ${firstname}
 </td>
{{/if}}
```

Is this thing possible..?

Comment: i think u can make it possible using the onload event of the tr giving the this to the function and then get the child tds with it and then deal with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think that [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes this a lot easier.

It is very possible. I assume that you would want this for each row. Lets assume you have the following table:

```
<table id="coolTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="anotherColumn">True</td>
        <td class="firstName">Chris</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="anotherColumn">False</td>
        <td class="firstName">Roger</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could go through rows and selectively add classes using the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#coolTable tr").each(function(i,row){
        if($(row).children("td.anotherColumn").html()=="True") // Any condition here
        {
            $(row).children("td.firstName").addClass("class1");
        }else{
            $(row).children("td.firstName").addClass("class2");
        }
    });
});
```

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrfunnel/LXq3w/2/

Comment: Thanks for this...how/where do I call the function within the markup..?

Comment: The down and dirty approach would be to put it into a script tag at the bottom of the page. <script type="text/javascript">...</script>

Comment: Sorry for the numbskull questions...but if I put it there does it just "automatically" get called or do I have to activate it somehow (like onclick=  but I know it's not onclick for this ;))

Comment: The $(function(){}); piece of the code is jQuery's document.ready shorthand. The functions within this are called once all page elements are loaded. You also need to include jQuery in the head of your page. Use this: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>. Gets jQuery from the google CDN. Super fast!

Comment: I couldn't get the function to work when called from document.ready, however I managed to find a function that was being called that I could plug your logic into and now works! Thanks for your help!